# Cannot resolve keyword 'author' into field

Tags: django

Here is the issue.I am trying to delete the tags related to my model. I can create them but whenever i try to use HTTP DELETE on ExampleModelTags, i face with the following issue.

Error: `Cannot resolve keyword 'author' into field. Choices are: id, examplemodel, examplemodel_id, tag, timestamp`

I can't understand what is the issue, i can create them so the algorithm works. The tags can connect to their parent model . But whenever i try to do HTTP DELETE on ExampleModelTags, i get that issue. Where is the problem that i don't see?

**Model.py**

```
class ExampleModelTag(models.Model):

    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    tag = models.CharField(max_length=35,null=True,blank=True)
    examplemodel = models.ForeignKey(ExampleModel, on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True,blank=True, related_name='examplemodeltags')
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)


class ExampleModel(models.Model):

    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True,related_name='examplemodels')
    examplemodel = models.CharField(unique=False,max_length=100,null=True,blank=True)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(unique=False,auto_now_add=True)
```

**Serializer.py**

```
class ExampleModelTagSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = ExampleModelTag
        fields = ("id","examplemodel","tag","timestamp")

    def validate(self, attrs):
        attrs = super().validate(attrs)
        if attrs['examplemodel'].author.id != self.context['request'].user.pk:
            raise ValidationError('Unauthorized Request')
        return attrs


class ExampleModelSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer): 
    examplemodeltags_set = ExampleModelTagSerializer(source='examplemodeltags',required=False,many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = ExampleModel
        fields = ("id","author","examplemodel","examplemodeltags_set","timestamp")

    def validate(self, attrs):
        attrs = super().validate(attrs)
        if attrs['author'].id != self.context['request'].user.pk:
            raise ValidationError('Unauthorized Request')
        return attrs
```

**Views.py**

```
class ExampleModelViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)
    queryset = ExampleModel.objects.all().order_by('-timestamp')
    serializer_class = ExampleModelSerializer
    filter_backends = [UserFilterBackend]

class ExampleModelTagViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)
    queryset = ExampleModelTag.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ExampleModelTagSerializer
    filter_backends = [UserFilterBackend]
```

**Filters.py**

```
class UserFilterBackend(filters.BaseFilterBackend):
    
    def filter_queryset(self, request, queryset, view):
        return queryset.filter(
            author=request.user
        )
```

Comment: Can you share your `ModelView` (or another `APIView` where you use the `ExampleModelSerializer`)?

Comment: please update your `views.py` code

Comment: Check the update please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not use the `UserFilterBackend` on the `ExampleModelTagViewSet`, since an `ExampleModelTag` has no `author` field. You thus should rewrite the `ExampleModelTagViewSet` to:

```
class ExampleModelTagViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    # ⋮
    filter_backends = []  # ← UserFilterBackend not applicable
```

If you want to fetch `ExampleModelTag`s for which an `ExampleModel` exists that links to that `ExampleModelTag` record, and has as `author` the logged in user, you can specify this with:

```
class ExampleModelAuthorBackend(filters.BaseFilterBackend):
    
    def filter_queryset(self, request, queryset, view):
        return queryset.filter(
            examplemodel__author=request.user
        )
```

and then use that one to filter the `ExampleModelTag`s:

```
class ExampleModelTagViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    # ⋮
    filter_backends = [ExampleModelAuthorBackend]
```

Comment: Exactly.I did not think the problem could arrive from this.Sometimes you do mistakes from too much automation (copy and paste) without checking it. 
I will use the second option. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

```
class UserFilterBackend(filters.BaseFilterBackend):
    
    def filter_queryset(self, request, queryset, view):
        return queryset.filter(
            examplemodel__author=request.user
        )
```

Comment: This will not work for the `ExampleModelViewSet`, since an `ExampleModel` has no `examplemodel` foreign key. You thus fixed it for the `ExampleModelTagViewSet`, but now it is broken for the `ExampleModelViewSet`.